# Sending arabic SMS by SMSlib in java

Tags: java, sms, arabic, smslib

i am using smslib in java for sending SMS with english letter it is working but i have problems when i am sending arabic letters .
 it display arabic character as a spaces ,i have tried a lot of sollutions but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SMS AT Command with a specific encoding solved the problem .